# How does Google Firestore work in the background?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

Recently, I started playing around with Google Cloud Firestore and I wonder, how does this thing work in the background. I read something about sockets, that they keep persist connection between client and server, instead of using classical HTTP requests.

Another feature is offline usage - when you make any change offline, content will be "cached" somewhere and when you go online, data are automatically send to the server.

And last thing is - I am using Angular for most of my projects and now, if I want some data from database, I don't have to make new subscription (sending new HTTP request). But, probably good thing is to keep only one open connection and when page is destroyed, I have to call unsubscribe to this object, right?

How do all these things work? Do you have any good resources or something?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of information on the internet and [Google](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/concepts) and [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) documentation that explains how these things work.

As you said offline usage allows to keep an application responsive in case of connectivity outage and maintains a cache of the changes until they can be resynchronized with the database, more information about offline data features [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/enable-offline). Data retrieval can be done as standalone operation where you query current state of documents data or as a reactive continuous operation where you attach a listener to a document to get acquainted of the changes made to it. You can find more information about the first [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) and about the second [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen).

Finally, Firebase has a [Youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCP4bf6IHJJQehibu6ai__cg) too with a ton of material that is worth checking.